# How to avoid post back code and use a hyperlink instead?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before I start, I should say that I don't really work with ASPX, I deal more with the styling, our developers haven't been able to help me with this.

Sorry about the title, I don't know how best to phrase it into a question.

---

We have a gridview with some generated hyperlinks which use some callback code which pops up an ugly window with some details about the item selected.

The client wants me to use a JQuery control called FancyBox which will display the page nicer.

The problem I am having is that Fancybox needs a standard `<a href="...` hyperlink to be able to launch the control with an iframe. I need to change the nasty `javascript:__doPostBack('gvGridView$ctl04$lnkOrderId','')` which is currently being generated, to a nice `/ClientOwnerDetails.aspx?OrderId=1234&FormId=4321`

The code on the aspx page:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Bind("OrderId") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("FormId") %>' ID="lnkOrderId" runat="server" OnClick="lnkOrderId_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The code behind which is generating this link:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "myscript", "window.open('./ClientOwnerDetails.aspx?OrderId=" + lnk.Text + "&FormId=" + lnk.CommandArgument + "','_blank');", true);
```

This is one of the last standing bugs which I need to work on today. Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need functionality of an aspx control, simply don't use it. The fact you use asp.net webforms doesn't mean you have to use these controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `asp:LinkButton`, you can do something like below which does not use JQuery.

```
<a href="/ClientOwnerDetails.aspx?OrderId=<%# Eval("OrderId") %>&FormId=<%# Eval("FormId") %>" target="_blank" id="lnkOrderId"><%# Eval("OrderId") %></a>
```

As mentioned you're using `GridView` control of `Asp.Net webforms`, and your client whants you to use Jquery, then you should any jquery grid (like http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/) and bind it using ajax. 
Posting a complete solution (which a very long) over here is not possible, you have to do it by own.

Comment: Jitendra, you posted more code then I was willing to.  I started then realized that it's been too many years since doing forms based ASPX and I'd have to look up the syntax for the binding.  Thanks.  I'll add my vote to your answer to push it up.

Comment: @THBBFT yeah, and i was thinking to post a complete solution of jquery ajax grid using pagination but stopped myself, because of huge amount of code. :P

Comment: That's good thanks! Thanks to @THBBFT as well! I had come up with the same solution before, just I couldn't get it to work and wasn't sure my formatting was correct. Currently got the "A call to a bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template". Working on that now.

Comment: yeah, actually I am working on MVC since 4+ years so wasn't sure about the correct function. Thanks, I'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

If the client wants you to use jQuery, use jQuery.  Dispense with the `asp.LinkButton` and add your own `a` tag.  The code in your `asp.LinkButton` explicitly is a server side control.